# Can you Refreeze baked/cooked chicken? How long can it stay in refrigerator after cooked?

Tags: meat

[image].

Can you Refreeze bake/cooked chicken?   How long is cooked meat good in refrigerator?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [USDA](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/freezing-and-food-safety/CT_Index/!ut/p/a1/jVHLbsIwEPyaHI2XhiLoLYpUAS2hiLaEXJBDNrGlxI5slxa-vgtV1Yegxb54Z2e0O2Oe8ZRnWmxVJbwyWtSHOuuvYQ797jCGyWzYvYVx8jyf3cUxDBbXRFj9QUjCC_VnTgT_6ScXDLiy03ha8awVXjKlS8PTCj0T2r2idTwtjSmYEyX6HSvFxjMnET01Dhg7dqXQRa10RWSLuKcXyQv2TcnT-HE91gW-8SXPfm4FXbrjJFz0RpMkhFnvN-FEbB-E87mQ8ao2-fGPVpHOwwE5tFiiRdt5sQRL79ubAALw0qotrSxNg3ltqs7GNAFIFLWXO2Zxo1p0FAzt_gUffaJlDdXukxTAqWnSOM_TU1N42zyl-_toBOqhWQ5c9A4Z33_l/#14):

> After cooking raw foods which were previously frozen, it is safe to freeze the cooked foods. If previously cooked foods are thawed in the refrigerator, you may refreeze the unused portion. Freeze leftovers within 3-4 days. Do not refreeze any foods left outside the refrigerator longer than 2 hours; 1 hour in temperatures above 90 °F.

Frozen foods typically remain safe indefinitely, but according to the USDA, cooked poultry can maintain its quality in a freezer after cooking for about 4 months.